# USB external drive not working

Tags: usb-drive

I have an external usb drive that is not working properly:

```
Jun 13 10:36:38 sleipneir kernel: [ 1022.548241] usb 1-3.1: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 28
Jun 13 10:36:38 sleipneir kernel: [ 1022.784404] usb 1-3.1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
Jun 13 10:36:38 sleipneir kernel: [ 1022.790785] scsi11 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
Jun 13 10:36:43 sleipneir kernel: [ 1027.835728] scsi 11:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ST320082 6A               3.03 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
Jun 13 10:36:43 sleipneir kernel: [ 1027.842150] sd 11:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
Jun 13 10:36:43 sleipneir kernel: [ 1027.845294] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] 390721968 512-byte logical blocks: (200 GB/186 GiB)
Jun 13 10:36:43 sleipneir kernel: [ 1027.847235] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
Jun 13 10:36:43 sleipneir kernel: [ 1027.849562]  sdb: sdb1 sdb2 < >
Jun 13 10:36:43 sleipneir kernel: [ 1027.900206] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

When I try to mount it, or to do anything else, here the errors:

```
Jun 13 10:37:51 sleipneir kernel: [ 1095.556228] usb 1-3.1: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 28
Jun 13 10:37:51 sleipneir kernel: [ 1096.068294] usb 1-3.1: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 28
Jun 13 10:37:52 sleipneir kernel: [ 1096.572234] usb 1-3.1: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 28
Jun 13 10:37:52 sleipneir kernel: [ 1097.004421] sd 11:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
Jun 13 10:37:52 sleipneir kernel: [ 1097.004451] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] Unhandled error code
Jun 13 10:37:52 sleipneir kernel: [ 1097.004457] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] Result: hostbyte=DID_ABORT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Jun 13 10:37:52 sleipneir kernel: [ 1097.004466] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 0b 44 32 00 00 00 f0 00
Jun 13 10:37:52 sleipneir kernel: [ 1097.004564] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] killing request
Jun 13 10:37:52 sleipneir kernel: [ 1097.004630] JBD: recovery failed
Jun 13 10:37:52 sleipneir kernel: [ 1097.004895] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] Unhandled error code
Jun 13 10:37:52 sleipneir kernel: [ 1097.004901] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Jun 13 10:37:52 sleipneir kernel: [ 1097.004909] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 0b 44 32 f0 00 00 10 00
Jun 13 10:37:52 sleipneir kernel: [ 1097.006532] usb 1-3.1: USB disconnect, address 28
Jun 13 10:37:52 sleipneir kernel: [ 1097.120164] usb 1-3.1: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 29
Jun 13 10:37:53 sleipneir kernel: [ 1097.636231] usb 1-3.1: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 30
Jun 13 10:37:53 sleipneir kernel: [ 1098.148342] usb 1-3.1: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 31
Jun 13 10:37:54 sleipneir kernel: [ 1098.652390] usb 1-3.1: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 32
```

Any ideas to recover it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Either the external drive or your machine's USB hardware is faulty. Test the drive in another machine, if it behaves the same replace it.

Answer (score 2):

It's also worth investigating the cable.

Some USB drives won't just work reliably on any old USB cable.
This can be due to cable length, quality and shielding issues.
If the cable you are using was shipped with the drive, then yep it's
probably a hardware problem. You also try on a different computer, maybe even running a different OS to eliminate issues with kernel version/device driver you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same here, problem was that I used a power supply with not enough power. Voltage was ok but it could not deliver enough ampere.